# geom_smooth in ggplot 2 not showing up because year are not in dates, but instead character vectors

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I have the following graph (below) that I would like to add a trend line to. However, I am having the same issue as this person has previously outlined: [geom_smooth in ggplot2 not working/showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560433/geom-smooth-in-ggplot2-not-working-showing-up).

However, I am unable to change the date to a data using as.date because it will not recognise only year e.g. 1999 as a date format (as opposed to dd-mm-yy).

Is there a simple way to get round this and add a trend line to the graph?

```
df <- data.frame(Year = c("2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"),
                 Proportion = c(46, 51, 48, 66, 60, 73, 61, 73, 60, 68, 74, 65)
)

#Create plot, labels etc.
graph1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = Proportion)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Proportion (%)") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) +
  geom_point(size = 3, colour = "red2") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(20, 80), breaks = seq(20, 80, by = 10)) 

graph1
```

Comment: `as.Date(paste0(Year, "-01-01"))` will come out as a `Date`-class column

Comment: `transform(df, Date = as.Date(paste0(Year, "-01-01"))) |> ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Proportion)) + geom_point() + ...`

Comment: Imperfectly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9322923/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6242955/3358272 (which have "Y-m", not just "Y" as you have here, but the solution is effectively the same).

Comment: If all you have is years, you can treat them as numbers instead of dates. Try `x = as.numeric(Year)` instead of `x = Year`. The `geom_smooth` will work perfectly well.

Comment: Or yet another way, specify your grouping manually. Adding `group = 1` to the `aes()` call will also work.